# Prisma Client update single record in one table where value in related table = true (Not creating related records)

Tags: next.js, prisma, next-auth

I am using next-auth, next.js, and prisma.

I want to update the `User` table, but only if the session token matches what is stored in the database. Prisma's documentation on CRUD (Related records) only provides examples how to create related records (Creating a user and posts at the same time). I only want to update a user if the session id is a match.

I would like to be able to do something like this, where the user is only updated if email + session id both match:

```
export default async (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse<User>) => {
  let email = req.query.email as string;
  let sessionId = req.query.email as string;
  let username = req.query.username as string;
  let zipcodeId = req.query.zipcodeId as string;

  const updatedUser = await prisma.user.update({
    where: { email: email, sessionId: sessionId },
    data: {
      username: username,
      zipcodeId: Number(zipcodeId),
    },
  });
  res.status(200).json(updatedUser);
};
```

```
// schema.prisma
model Session {
  id           String   @id @default(cuid())
  sessionToken String   @unique @map("session_token")
  userId       Int      @map("user_id")
  user         User     @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)
  expires      DateTime
  
}

model User {
  id            Int    @id @default(autoincrement())
  name          String?
  email         String?   @unique
  emailVerified DateTime?
  image         String?
  username     String?   @unique
  accounts      Account[]
  sessions      Session[]
  votes         Vote[]
  zipcodeId     Int?      @map("zipcode_id")
  zipcode       Zipcode?  @relation(fields: [zipcodeId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use `updateMany` in this scenario as the fields which have `@unique` attribute can only be passed in where clause of update query.

Here's the query through which you could add condition of email and sessionId

```js
  const updatedUser = await prisma.user.updateMany({
    where: {
      email: 'email@email.com',
      sessions: {
        every: {
          id: '1',
        },
      },
    },
    data: {
      username: 'username',
    },
  });
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I actually realized I don't need to do this myself via prisma, but can instead secure the next route using the methods mentioned here: https://next-auth.js.org/tutorials/securing-pages-and-api-routes